# Proving linear equations/Inequalities automatically

Tags: automation, equation, algebra, theorem-proving, inequality

I'm looking for a tool for determining whether a given set of linear equations/inequalities (A) entails another given set of linear equations/inequalities (B). The return value should be either 'true' or 'false'.

To illustrate, let's look at possible instances of A and B and the expected return value of the algorithm:

```
A: {Z=3,Y=Z+2, X < Y} ;
B: {X<5} ; 
Expected result: true

A: {Z=3,Y=Z+2, X < Y} ;
B: {X<10} ;
Expected result: true

A: {Z=3,Y=Z+2, X < Y} ;
B: {X=3} ; 
Expected result: false

A: {X<=Y,X>=Y} ;
B: {X=Y} ; 
Expected result: true

A: {X<=Y,X>=Y} ;
B: {X=Y, X>Z+2} ; 
Expected result: false
```

Typically A contains up to 10 equations/inequalities, and B contains 1 or 2.  All of them are linear and relatively simple. We may even assume that all variables are integers.

This task - of determining whether A entails B - is part of a bigger system and therefore I'm looking for tools/source code/packages that already implemented something like that and I can use.

Things I started to look at:

> 1. Theorem provers with algebra - Otter, EQP and Z3 (Vampire is currently unavailable for download).
> 2. Coq formal proof management system.
> 3. Linear Programming.

However, my experience with these tools is very limited and so far I didn't find a promising direction. Any guidelines and ideas from people more experienced than me will be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a working solution. The problem can be rephrased as an assignment problem and then it can be solved by theorem provers such as Z3 and with some work probably also by linear programming solvers.

To illustrate, let's look at the first example I gave above:

```
A: {Z=3, Y=Z+2, X<Y} ;
B: {X<5} ;
```

Determining whether A entails B is equivalent to determining whether it is impossible that A is true while B is false. This is a simple simple logical equivalence. In our case, it means that rather than checking whether the condition in B follows from the ones in A, we can check whether there is no assignment of X, Y and Z that satisfies the conditions in A and not in B.

Now, when phrased as an assignment problem, a theorem prover such as Z3 can be called for the task. The following code checks if the conditions in A are satisfiable while the one in B is not:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun z () Int)
(assert (= z 3))
(assert (= y (+ z 2))) 
(assert (< x y))
(assert (not (< x 5)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

Z3 reports that there is no model that satisfies these conditions, thus it is not possible that B doesn't follow from A, and therefore we can conclude that B follows from A.